# jQuery function does not execute for classes aded with d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

The following code is part of my JS file. This simply adds a circle. Everything is drawn fine and with firebug or any other inspector I can see that classes are set correctly.

```
d3.json("relations", function(error, graph) {
   var node_circle = svg.selectAll()
            .data(graph.nodes).enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "circle launch-node-modal")
            .attr("data-toggle", "modal")
            .attr("data-target", "#myModal")
            .attr("data-action", function(d) { return d.url; })
            .attr("data-title", "Generic Element Details")
            .attr("r", circle_r);
    }
}
```

Then, in the same JS file, I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(function (){
    $('.launch-node-modal').on('click', function () {

    });
});
```

The problem is that when I click the circle, the function is not triggered. Moreover, as you can see, I have two attributes `data-togle` and `data-target`, which together when I click the circle, they launch my modal. So attributes and classes are set correctly. But why my function doesn't catch that `launch-node-modal` on click?

Is there any trick to make a connection between `d3` and `jQuery`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a d3 issue, as an issue of any dynamically added content. What you want to do is delegate the click event. That means you tie the click event to something that exists on page load (for example, the body) and then on the click check to see what element was clicked. Here is the code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.launch-node-modal', function() { });
```

Comment: Finally found the magic trick. And I think it is a d3 issue. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try $('body').on('click', '.launch-node-modal', function()

Answer (score 0):

After searching the answer for 30 minutes, finally got the magic trick:

```
d3.json("relations", function(error, graph) {
   var node_circle = svg.selectAll()
            .data(graph.nodes).enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "circle launch-node-modal")
            .attr("data-toggle", "modal")
            .attr("data-target", "#myModal")
            .attr("data-action", function(d) { return d.url; })
            .attr("data-title", "Generic Element Details")
            .attr("r", circle_r)
            .on('click', function () {
                 alert('SOF');
             });
    }
}
```

So the solution was to stop using jQuery and integrate the code directly